# syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using RSpec to run some tests, I get the following error:

```
/spec/requests/booking_applications_spec.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)
```

Here's the file:

spec/requests/booking_applications_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Booking applications", :type => :request do

  describe "POST new booking application" do

    it "creates a new booking application" do
      BookingApplication.destroy_all
      BookingApplication.count.should == 0      

      params = { format: :json, booking_application: { driver_id: 1 } } #Error
      post :create, :booking_id => 1, params

      BookingApplication.count.should == 1
      response.status.should eq(200)
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error seem to be in the next line:

```
  post :create, :booking_id => 1, params
```

You need to change it to:

```
  post :create, params.merge(booking_id: 1)
```

Or include `booking_id: 1` in params at once.

Ruby cannot parse options hash in the end of method call, it expects smth like

```
  post :create, :booking_id => 1, params => 'something'
```