# Cannot assign stripe_account_id to Stripe Order

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Stripe's support says nothing is wrong with their [ruby code](https://stripe.com/docs/relay/apps-guide#create-orders) but I'm sure there is.

Im trying to assign a `stripe_user_id` to an order but having so such luck. Erooro

```
Stripe::Order.create(
  :currency => 'gbp',
  :email => 'demo@demo.com',
  :items => [
    {
      :type => 'sku',
      :parent => "sku_******",
    }
  ],
  :metadata => {:key => "some_key" },
  {:stripe_account => User.first.stripe_user_id}
)
```

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Is not that the correct syntax? That's what stripe showed in the example for Ruby.

Comment: this is not a Stripe error but a Ruby error. It looks like you have a newline character where it isn't expected. Try first of all to make the above code into a single line .. and if that doesn't help try to print out all your dynamic values (according to your code that could be at least `some_key` and `User.first.stripe_user_id` and ensure they are as expected.

Comment: Hi @PeterTheill Ive figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Faron** explained that [Ruby cannot parse options hash in the end of method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821936/syntax-error-unexpected-n-expecting-syntaxerror). So I assumed that Stipe example is wrong or not clear.

**So based on that I did this:**

```
order_obj = {
 :currency => 'gbp',
  :email => 'demo@demo.com',
  :items => [
    {
      :type => 'sku',
      :parent => "sku_******",
    }
  ],
  :metadata => {:key => "some_value" }
}
```

**Now pass in the option (connected account id) with the hash:**

```
Stripe::Order.create(order_obj, {:stripe_account => User.first.stripe_user_id})
```

I think if Stripe had this example, noobs like me would understand better.